# COnditional Formatting with Multiple Criterias

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have been trying to do Conditional formatting for a Column of Date. 
Column A: Actual end date , Column B : Proposed End date.

Column A dates should be formatted to Red Font Automatically if the dates are greater than the proposed dates on Column B and also if the dates are less than ( ex.: 18.5.2015 ) today's date (22.5.2015) .

I tried the Formula ,"=A2>B2, A2< TODAY() " in the formatting manager dialogue box.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When assigning conditional formulas, you need to use absolute references for the column or row that you wish to hold constant. Additionally, the `AND()` formula is needed to provide the Boolean AND that your code requires. The following snippet should work:

```
=AND($A2>$B2,$A2<TODAY())
```

One additional comment: I would avoid using `TODAY()` or other volatile formulas in conditional formatting. On large worksheets, this can seriously impact performance. My recommendation would be to create a cell with the formula `=TODAY()` and reference that cell in your formula, as shown in the following example (the cell containing today's date has been named `Today`):

```
=AND($A2>$B2,$A2<Today)
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Brett. It didnt work out when i used AND function.Dont know where i made a mistake. But I used the same formula without AND function, as a seperate formula and it worked.